# passing parameters using selected value from combo box in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox, .net-4.5

I have a `combobox1` on my form which is bound by a data source, it displays values from my data table.

I then have `combobox2` which needs to populate but the store procedure that fires requires a parameter.

How can i pass the selectedValue from `combobox1` into the datasource so that combobox2 will show up with its values?

This is my code so far:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string databaseName = string.Empty;
    if (comboBox1.SelectedValue != null) databaseName = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
    comboBox2.DataSource(FindColumn.GetData(databaseName));
}
```

Comment: What issue you facing in posted code?

Comment: My `combobox2` does nothing.. No values are populated and the stored proc doesnt even fire.

Comment: @RohitVats can you help? I just need to know how to populate my `combobox2` and pass in my parameter `databaseName`

Comment: Check if Combo1 has autopostback property on true. By default they never postback when selecting options.

Answer (score 0):

This is example how to get `ComboBox` binded to `DataTable` data source and how to get the value out of selected item (so that later you can use that value to fill another combobox)

```
 // On constructor - Quickly create some table and fill with some data
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt.Columns.Add("a");
 dt.Columns.Add("b");
 dt.Columns.Add("c");
 dt.Rows.Add("1", "2", "aaa");
 dt.Rows.Add("3", "4", "bbb");
 // setup combo box data binding
 comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
 comboBox1.DisplayMember = "b";
 comboBox1.ValueMember = "a";
```

Notice that we don't reference column "c"

```
void button1_click()
{
    MessageBox.Show(((DataRowView )comboBox1.SelectedItem)[2].ToString ());
}
```

This will result in "aaa" or "bbb" shown. Now, you can use that value to call your stored proc.

Basically, when you bind `DataTable`, each combo item is a `DataRowView`. All your table data is available for the row you've selected.

Notice

```
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "b";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "a";
```

Usually this is enough. You would use some id as `ValueMember` and use that id to do your CRUD operations. But again, example above shows that you can have more different values available via `SelectedItem` property.